# Cancel order when invoice paid Magento?

Tags: magento, invoice

As I am beginner magento developer unable to create the credit memo as paypal return that invoice already refunded.

How can i create memo and change invoice status, also change order status to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

When a payment is cancelled in Paypal, it will create a credit memo automatically. 
The status assigned to a refund order within Magento is usually **"closed"**.